# modifying u-boot environment in kernel init

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot

I'm trying to modify a u-boot env arg within the kernel code.
I've found `boot_command_line` var in `main.c` and `setup.c`, which contains an arg, so that made me think it is possible, however, I coudn't find where this var is being updated with the u-boot env arg value,
or how to get a different arg and then write it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong approach.  There are user-space tools to access the U-Boot environment, `fw_printenv` and `fw_setenv` and that's how you access the environment outside of U-Boot.

Comment: I understand it may be a wrong approach, but can I access them from kernel?

Comment: The best answer here is no.  There's nothing in the kernel to do what you're looking for, and everything you want is and can be done today from user space.  The worst answer is yes, both U-Boot and the Linux Kernel are GPL-v2.  Copy whatever code you need from U-Boot to the kernel to be able to access the environment and go.